# KitKat ART-build warning

Tags: android, warnings

I have an application that runs perfectly with KitKat 4.4.2 and the ART-build, however I get a warning when swiping between my fragments. I have Tabs+Viewpager using ActionBarSherlock:

```
    01-13 14:26:20.550  28671-28671/com.test.xxx W/art﹕ Attempt to
    remove local SIRT entry from IRT, ignoring 
    01-13 14:26:20.640 28671-29243/com.test.xxx W/art: 
   Thread[26,tid=29243,Native,Thread*=0x4486f6b0,peer=0x64a178e8,"Thread-2333"] 
   attached without supplying a name
```

Is this something to be worried about or can I just ignore it? The only information I found about it was in the android source code:

```
    void Runtime::AttachCurrentThread(const char* thread_name, bool as_daemon, 
    Object* thread_group) {
    Thread::Attach(thread_name, as_daemon, thread_group);
    if (thread_name == NULL) {
    LOG(WARNING) << *Thread::Current() << " attached without supplying a name";
         }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to affect the build or compatibility, but nope no answers as of yet.

Comment: still nothing? getting this as well

Comment: Nope and can't test it anymore, my xperia don't have the option for ART.... Can someone confirm this happens with appcompat as well?

Comment: I get this once per second while running one of the [tag:android-ndk] samples.